# JSON.stringify gives something completely different

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var tempid = document.getElementById("TDID1");
```

Using `alert(JSON.stringify(tempid))` Gives

> {"jQuery3600419938127216425761":{"events":{"click":[{"type":"click","origType":"click","data":null,"guid":14,"namespace":""}]}}}

When all i want it to give is a variable typeof sting with `document.getElementById("TDID1")`

Comment: Can you add the HTML to your question? Maybe just the element with the id TDID1. And what value is it that you are interested in?

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` creates a string for the value you give it. When that value is an object, the string is JSON describing all of the own, enumerable properties of the object.

In your case, the object is a DOM element, and one on which jQuery has been used at some point.

> When all i want it to give is a variable typeof sting with `document.getElementById("TDID1")`

If I understand you correctly, that's not what `JSON.stringify` is for. You could write the string directly of course:

```
const str = 'document.getElementById("TDID1")';
```

...but there's no way, starting from the value returned by `getElementById`, to construct a string for the way you accessed that value.

Or if you want the value of that element (assuming it's an `input` or `select` element), you could get that value from `.value`:

```
const value = document.getElementById("TDID1").value;
```

Or if you want the *text content* of a non-`input` element:

```
const text = document.getElementById("TDID1").textContent;
```

Or if you want the inner HTML of the element:

```
const html = document.getElementById("TDID1").innerHTML;
```

Or the *outer* HTML of the element:

```
const html = document.getElementById("TDID1").outerHTML;
```